# remove grub using from inside windows 7

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7

last year I installed Ubuntu on my pc and everything worked fine then one day i accidentally removed the Ubuntu partition but the boot menu that allow u to choose between windows 7 and Ubuntu was still there. Found a guide that allow u to remove Ubuntu or other from this menu using command prompt inside windows 7 (no disk,no downloads)(everything worked fine then)

Now i need these command again but i cant find them anywhere

anyone can help PLEASE??????

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

EasyBCD is a software utility for Windows that lets you control and configure the BCD/BOOTMGR boot loader for Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8.

<sup>Source:EasyBCD</sup>